# Undefined variable while unquoting in macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Here is my macro definition:

```
*(defmacro run-test (test)
   `(format t "Run test ~a ... ~a" ',test ,test))
*(run-test (= 1 1))
Run test (= 1 1) ... T
NIL
```

Everything works fine for now, so I've defined a second macro (to run multiple tests):

```
*(defmacro run-tests (&body body) 
   `(loop for tc in ',body 
      do (run-test tc)))
* (run-tests (= 2 (1+ 1)) (= 1 1))
Run test TC ... (= 2 (1+ 1) Run test TC ... (= 1 1)
```

This result is not I wanted, I wanted each value of `tc` to be replaced by the sexp and the value be evaluated in run-test. i tried to replace the line

```
          do (run-test tc)
```

with

```
          do (run-test ,tc)
```

but this signals an error

> Undefined variable: TC

How can I change this to get the right result?

Answer (score 10):

Look at the expansion of e.g. `(run-tests (= 1 1))`:

```
(loop for tc in '((= 1 1)) do (run-test tc))
```

As you can see, the code tries to call `(run-test tc)`.  But `run-test` operates on a form; it will not work when you pass a variable *containing* a form.

If you change your code to `(run-test ,tc)` you are trying to refer to the `tc` variable during macroexpansion time, but it's only bound at runtime.

One solution would be to do more at macroexpansion time:

```
(defmacro run-tests (&body body)
  `(progn ,@(loop for tc in body collect `(run-test ,tc))))
```

Comment: I like the possible solution that uses `loop` to construct the macroexpansion.  It's generally a useful approach to write by hand, at least once, the code the _desired_ code that the macro should expand to.  In this case, it'd be `(progn (run-test form1) (run-test form2) ...)` and, when seen in that light, `loop` is clearly a good way to get it.

Comment: Very good solution. I looked details of LISP macro again. I was wrong to understand the macro expand phase and runtime phase.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an exercise. You could get rid of the macros:

```
(defun run-test (test)
  (format t "~%Run test ~a ... ~a" test (eval test)))

(defun run-tests (tests)
  (mapc 'run-test tests)
  (values))

* (run-tests '((= 2 (1+ 1))
               (= 1 1)))
```

Comment: Yes, actually, writing a function is straightforward for me, as a Python player. It is just for me to learn the macro of LISP. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @WuLi Never use a macro, where a function would suffice. If you absolutely want to do this, you probably want to consider what the body would return, were it a function (and for nesting, this applies to the exact form at the site where you want the expansion to happen, ignoring what variabel bindings happen to be in force, macros are source-code transformations after all).

Comment: @Vatine: Yes, "never use a macro where a function would suffice" is a good rule of thumb, but so is "eval is evil". I think a macro is a good approach for this task, if done correctly, and has the advantage of not needing a quote on the arguments. But it's true that the `eval` approach is easier to get right, and since testing functions are meant to be used during development rather than the actual runtime of a program, it's somewhat more acceptable here.